# batch file to list folders within a folder to one level

Tags: batch-file

I have searched and searched to no avail so apologies if the answer does exist.

I am not very good with batch files so please keep this in mind.

All I am after is a single batch file that will list/save to file a list of the folders within the current folder.

So basically if I run this batch file within a certain folder it will output all folders (not files or sub folders, just to one level) within the folder from which the batch file was run.

I assume this is probably an easy request however I have not had any luck on Google, etc.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### Dir

Use the `dir` command.  Type in [`dir /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) for help and options.

```
dir /a:d /b
```

---

### Redirect

Then use a redirect to save the list to a file.

```
> list.txt
```

---

### Together

```
dir /a:d /b > list.txt
```

This will output just the names of the directories. if you want the full path of the directories use this below.

---

### Full Path

```
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /a:d /b') do echo %%~fD
```

---

### Alternative

other method just using the `for` command.  See `for /?` for help and options.  This can output just the name `%%~nxD` or the full path `%%~fD`

```
for /d %%D in (*) do echo %%~fD
```

---

### Notes

To use these commands directly on the command line, change the double percent signs to single percent signs. `%%` to `%`

To redirect the `for` methods, just add the redirect after the echo statements.  Use the double arrow `>>` redirect here to append to the file, else only the last statement will be written to the file due to overwriting all the others.

```
... echo %%~fD>> list.txt
```

Comment: Ok, I have the following: for /D %%A IN (*) DO echo %%A>> output.txt but the result seems to be in date order. How do I sort by name. Regards, Jonny

Comment: Unfortunately, to easily sort the results you will want to use the `dir` command. The only other option is to use the `sort` command. Add the `/o:n` parameter to the `dir` command.  See `dir /?` for all the options.  Here are the two `dir` commands updated. `dir /a:d /b /o:n > output.txt` or `for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /a:d /b /o:n') do echo %%~fD>> output.txt`

Answer (score 2):

print all folders name where batch script file is kept

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /d %%d in (*.*) do (
    set test=%%d
    echo !test!
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this command to display the list of files in the directory.

`dir /s /b > List.txt`

In the file it displays the list below.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Cisco Jabber\XmppMgr.dll
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Cisco Jabber\XmppSDK.dll
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Cisco Jabber\accessories\Plantronics
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Cisco Jabber\accessories\SennheiserJabberPlugin.dll
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Cisco Jabber\accessories\Logitech\LogiUCPluginForCisco
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Cisco Jabber\accessories\Logitech\LogiUCPluginForCisco\lucpcisco.dll

What is want to do is only to display sub-directory not the full directory path.

Just like this:

> Cisco Jabber\XmppMgr.dll Cisco Jabber\XmppSDK.dll
>
> Cisco Jabber\accessories\JabraJabberPlugin.dll
>
> Cisco Jabber\accessories\Logitech
>
> Cisco Jabber\accessories\Plantronics
>
> Cisco Jabber\accessories\SennheiserJabberPlugin.dll